# Get Currency Symbol using REST API

Tags: rest, currency

Is there anyway to find out the Currency Symbol used for Currency fields using REST API?

Comment: What about your org? Is it single currency or multi-currency?

Comment: I generally need to know for a single currency org but I have a dev edition for multi-currency which I also have the same problem for multi-currency.

Answer (score 1):

This information is not available since all Salesforce provides is the ISO code. Your best bet is to use a site like http://www.xe.com/symbols.php to create an APEX utility class to get a symbol by ISO code. I will check to see if I already have one and if I do I will add a gist to this answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

See if this help. This is the org where Multicurrency is not enabled.
PFA where you can get currency symbol.

[image]